# Xamarin: How to implement NSDictionary with YES

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to create a `NSDictionary` in `Xamarin/C#` with `YES` Value.
The `NSDictionary` in `Objective-C` looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *requestSettings = @{
    kKeyOne : @YES,
    kKeyTwo : @YES
};
```

I have no idea where in `Xamarin` I can find the `YES` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary dict = new NSMutableDictionary();

dict.Add("test", new NSNumber(true));
```

Answer (score 2):

To set values in Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, bool> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, bool>();

dictionary.Add("kKeyOne", true);
dictionary.Add("kKeyTwo", true);
```

To get the value -

```
bool value = dictionary["kKeyOne"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CFBoolean.True and CFBoolean.False for your values.

Comment: CFBoolean Class does not exist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone like Miguel knows Xamarin. :o

Comment: CFBoolean.True is inaccessible due to its protection level. Use NSNumber(true) instead: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41164